# Removing the object from nested json using its key and value (Java script or jQuery)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

I need to remove the one object from json data....My JSON would be like this

This is my JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "comp2": [
            {
                "Create_SecurityGroup1_Securitygroup_name": {
                    "description": "sg"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "comp1": [
            {
                "Create_Keypair1_Keypair_name": {
                    "default": "kp"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to remove "comp1" or "comp2" datas ...this key values are dynamic...but structure is same...
    Once i removed the key from this JSON data ...My result would like this if i remove "comp2"..

```
[
       {
        "comp1": [
            {
                "Create_Keypair1_Keypair_name": {
                    "default": "kp"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Please help me to solve this issue ....

Comment: Hi can you share u r code in plunker.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove data from json object then u can use the slice method which work for json and array.

```
var recentActdata = [   
{ 
    "displayValue":"Updated Guidelines", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"29/06/2013 01:32"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Logging", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"28/06/2013 16:19"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Subscribe", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"21/06/2013 14:30"
}]


$.each(recentActdata.slice(0,5), function(i, data) {
    var ul_data = "<li><h3>"+ data.displayValue+ "</h3></li>";
    $("#recentActivities").append(ul_data);
});
```

Here is a demo example you can see the use of slice

use following link

http://jsfiddle.net/enXcn/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the JSON, your format is a little odd.  There's really no reason to put every element inside an array.  This would be plenty valid and accomplish the same...

```
var json = { "comp2": { 
    "Create_SecurityGroup1_Securitygroup_name": { 
        "description": "sg" 
        } 
    } 
}, 
{ "comp1": { 
    "Create_Keypair1_Keypair_name": { 
        "default": "kp" 
        } 
    }
}
```

with this format, you simply use...

```
delete json["comp2"];
```

If you do not have control of your format, then you'll need to access the 1st element in the array first...

```
delete json[0]["comp2"];
```